# How to Regain/Set Focus in a Mac OS Swift Application

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

In one of my views I called a modal dialog like the:

```
  let application = NSApplication.shared()
  application.runModal(for: artistDialogWindow)
```

When the OK or Cancel button are pressed, I terminate the modal window like this:

```
let application = NSApplication.shared()
application.stopModal()
```

The view that called the dialog regains control. After it runs so code, it exits. On the screen, it appears that no window has focus. If I click on the title bar of my window, the red, orange, and green buttons on the left of the title bar go from gray to color. How can I do this programmatically?

I tried NSApplication.activate. It doesn't do anything. Presumably my app is already active. It just doesn't have focus. I also tried selecting a row in a table in the view. The row is selected, but the window is not.

Comment: NSWindow documentation gives you methods like orderFront: for example... now you just need a reference to the window that should go front. Or you run the dialog modal to the current window... than it shouldn't be necessary at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try NSWindow's makeKey(). Or makeKeyAndOrderFront(_ sender: Any?). These activate the window.

For example, a `niceWindow` has to be focused (you need a reference to the window that you want to bring focus to). Then do:

```
niceWindow.makeKey()
```

or

```
niceWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
```

Comment: I got it to work with self.view.window!.makeKey(). Change your question to an answer so others may benefit and I'll accept it.

Comment: Done. Glad to provide help!

Comment: Could the working code be posted? I have the exact same issue but can't make it work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581740/how-to-bring-focus-to-window-after-closing-modal-in-swift-3-for-macos

Comment: @billyhafiz, I've updated the answer. Did it work for you?